# 산 중에 제일 높은 산은 백두산이고 가장 아름다운 산은 금강산입니다. The "이고" works as usual?

Tags: usage

이고

Each noun are connected as the same level by it.

For example.

부장이고 사장이고 ...　The leader and the boss , all is ...

옷이고 신이고 ...     The clothes and the shoes , all is ...

But...

산 중에 제일 높은 산은 백두산**이고** 가장 아름다운 산은 금강산입니다.

It is little weird to me. It seems that this sentence is different a little.

I can understand if this sentence is as follows:

백두산 **이고** 금강산 **이고** 조선의 산 입니다.

But the subject sentence has two nouns and they are written separately.

Nonetheless, 이고 is used...

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

이고 in your sentence just means 'and'.

Translated:
Among mountains, the highest mountain **is** 백두산, **and** the most beautiful mountain is 금강산.

The 이고 in the sentence comes from 이다 (to be) + ~고 (and, grammar point to make and-form of a verb), so 이고 is used to state two different things on each side of the 이고, just like the English 'and'.